# RuntimeException could not be mapped to a response, re-throwing to the HTTP container com.hp.hpl.jena.update.UpdateException

Tags: response, jena, virtuoso

i have a REST service for sending data to a triplestore:

```
VirtGraph virtGraph = new VirtGraph ("jdbc:virtuoso://localhost:1111", "demo", "demo");
Model virtModel = new VirtModel(virtGraph);
VirtuosoUpdateRequest vur = VirtuosoUpdateFactory.create(str, virtGraph);
vur.exec();
virtGraph.close();
```

and although the data are stored the response i get is:

```
com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerResponse mapMappableContainerException
SEVERE: The RuntimeException could not be mapped to a response, re-throwing to the HTTP container
com.hp.hpl.jena.update.UpdateException: Convert results are FAILED.:
    at virtuoso.jena.driver.VirtuosoUpdateRequest.exec(VirtuosoUpdateRequest.java:72)
```

All the libraries needed are in the web folder of the project. Any ideas please?

Comment: Not a Jena message - it must come from the Virtuoso adapter.

Comment: and how can i check that? because althought i get the exception message the info i try to store is stored properly in virtuoso

Comment: Product-specific questions are often best raised to product-specific arenas. [Virtuoso](http://virtuoso.openlinksw.com/) (from my employer, [OpenLink Software](http://www.openlinksw.com/)) has a [Users mailing list](https://lists.sourceforge.net/lists/listinfo/virtuoso-users/), public [Support forums](http://boards.openlinksw.com/support/index.php), confidential [Support cases](http://support.openlinksw.com/support/online-support.vsp)… Best first thing to check is always that you are using latest Virtuoso, JDBC driver, Jena provider, etc.

Comment: @TallTed - thanks for clarifying - could you add that to the "virtuoso" tag information?